# Finding most recent rows based on matching same id in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is the [DB Fiddle link to all the data in this question](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tJs5nf7TM2r2EEezeyMN8w/0)

### The Setup

I have a sql database table that shows a list of flights and the staff that were assigned to that flight. The `crsday` column is used a "date column" but is actually a VARCHAR column, and unfortunately I have no way to edit this database design.

For simplicity I have cut it down, but in essence multiple people can all have the same flight_id. For this demo, if you look in the table, you will see that every row containing `Me` with `staff_number` `12345` will match with one other staff member.

| id | flight_id | staff_number | name | crsday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1979-01-22_XX-283-MAD | 54976 | Anna Arty | 14233 |
| 2 | 2014-12-13_XX-653-NCE | 65223 | Benny Box | 25431 |
| 3 | 1997-09-04_XX-920-VCE | 98221 | Charlie Chaplen | 20098 |
| 4 | 1980-05-08_XX-968-DUB | 12293 | Denny Dox | 19877 |
| 5 | 2011-01-30_XX-158-LHR | 48322 | Emma End | 21324 |
| 6 | 2003-05-23_XX-688-JFK | 12345 | Me | 20887 |
| 7 | 1976-02-17_XX-571-BRU | 65223 | Benny Box | 12098 |
| 8 | 2017-06-16_XX-91-IAD | 54976 | Anna Arty | 26544 |
| 9 | 2007-05-22_XX-609-AMS | 48322 | Emma End | 22823 |
| 10 | 1999-04-16_XX-805-ORK | 65223 | Benny Box | 19800 |
| 11 | 1974-09-21_XX-895-SNN | 98221 | Charlie Chaplen | 13422 |
| 12 | 2001-04-15_XX-24-BEL | 12293 | Denny Dox | 18776 |
| 13 | 2003-05-23_XX-688-JFK | 98221 | Charlie Chaplen | 20887 |
| 14 | 1990-09-02_XX-620-DUS | 48322 | Emma End | 16772 |
| 15 | 1971-11-19_XX-113-FRA | 98221 | Charlie Chaplen | 10223 |
| 16 | 2017-06-16_XX-91-IAD | 12345 | Me | 26544 |
| 17 | 2005-07-07_XX-881-AGP | 12293 | Denny Dox | 21652 |
| 18 | 2011-02-22_XX-816-ALC | 65223 | Benny Box | 24539 |
| 19 | 1986-02-10_XX-107-EWR | 12345 | Me | 17655 |
| 20 | 1994-05-05_XX-802-BIO | 48322 | Emma End | 16543 |
| 21 | 2010-08-10_XX-673-BOS | 12345 | Me | 24879 |
| 22 | 1997-09-11_XX-934-RIO | 12293 | Denny Dox | 17302 |
| 23 | 1979-10-16_XX-258-BUD | 48322 | Emma End | 14289 |
| 24 | 1975-06-23_XX-684-MAN | 98221 | Charlie Chaplen | 11820 |
| 25 | 2010-08-10_XX-673-BOS | 12293 | Denny Dox | 24879 |
| 26 | 1988-11-20_XX-238-BHX | 48322 | Emma End | 17629 |
| 27 | 1994-02-18_XX-383-GLA | 12293 | Denny Dox | 18352 |
| 28 | 1986-02-10_XX-107-EWR | 54976 | Anna Arty | 17655 |
| 29 | 1984-04-04_XX-768-LGW | 98221 | Charlie Chaplen | 15429 |
| 30 | 1987-05-26_XX-246-BRS | 65223 | Benny Box | 16266 |

### Query

I would like to run a query that does the following:

Knowing MY own staff number of `12345`, and given a list of OTHER staff numbers, please return the row of the most recent time we both were assigned the same flight.

For example:

My staff number is `12345` (Me). If I am given 2 staff numbers,  `54976` (Anna Arty) and `12293` (Denny Dox), how could I write a query that would give me the following result:

| id | flight_id | staff_number | name | crsday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 2017-06-16_XX-91-IAD | 54976 | Anna Arty | 26544 |
| 25 | 2010-08-10_XX-673-BOS | 12293 | Denny Dox | 24879 |

Or even just the actual `flight_id` by itself would be fine.

If you look in the source table you can see that I have be assigned to the same flight with `Anna Arty` twice before (id/row `8 + 16` and `19 + 28`) but the most *recent* one was the one with the higher `crsday` value.

My trouble is not that I'm lazy - it took me ages to get all this demo data created! I would rather have spent this time just solving the problem....only I genuinely have no idea how to even go about tackling this problem!

I have always been poor as mysql/sql queries, but always stumbled through. With this one I just don't know where to begin.

Any help would be very grately receieved. Thank you very much.

Again, Here is the [DB Fiddle link to all the data in this question](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tJs5nf7TM2r2EEezeyMN8w/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-join and aggregation:

```
select h.staff_number, max(h.crsday)
from history h join
     history h_me
     on h.flight_id = h_me.flight_id and
        h_me.staff_number = 12345
group by h.staff_number;
```

Note:  This assumes that whatever the format of `crsday`, you can use `max(crsday)` to get the most recent date.

EDIT:

To get the flight id on the most recent date:

```
select h.*
from (select h.staff_number, h.crsday, h.flight_id,
             row_number() over (partition by h.staff_number order by h.crsday desc) as seqnum
      from history h join
           history h_me
           on h.flight_id = h_me.flight_id and
              h_me.staff_number = 12345
     ) h
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can add a `where` clause in the subquery to limit the staff to whatever list you want.

EDIT II:

In older versions of MySQL, you can use this trick (assuming the number of flights in common does not exceed the length of string concatenation):

```
select h.staff_number, max(h.crsday),
       substring_index(group_concat(h.flight_id order by h.crsday desc), ',', 1) as flight_id
from history h join
     history h_me
     on h.flight_id = h_me.flight_id and
        h_me.staff_number = 12345
group by h.staff_number;
```

Alternatively, you can join back to the `h_me` table to get information about the flights on the maximum day.

Comment: don't you need another condition: `h.staff_number <> 12345` or anything to remove the duplicated rows

Comment: Ok thank you for this start! I appreciate that.

Just a few things, so far doesn't return a flight_id, which is the most important bit of data to get. Also, my real table has **thousands** of staff members, so I need to be able to provide and limit the query to only the staff numbers I provide. So in this example, say I only wanted to search the table for OTHER staff numbers `54976` and `12293` that matched with me `12345`.

I'll start and play around with it. Thanks

Comment: Ok I've created a fork db-fiddle here that almost works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d7tyTB4s179nrVQwpz3LV/0   I have the information I want, but the trouble is that I have 2 rows for "Anna Arty" and not just the most recent. I'm almost 100% sure it's because of the `group by` at the end and including more fields in there, but if I remove them I get a mysql error. Any nudges in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. I see your edit. The result is exactly the information I was looking for so I will mark the question as answered because you have been so kind to spend time helping me. My only issue is that the server that runs this is using mysql 5.7 and so the mysql 8 syntax in the answer won't work on it! I need to find a polyfill or convert it to mysql 5.7 syntax!